# Prove that there exist a prime having last $65050$ digits the largest known prime

Tags: number-theory

The largest known prime is of the $65050$ digits. Prove that there exist another prime which ends in the same $65050$ digits of largest known prime.

Comment: Isn't the largest known prime already an example of a prime which ends in the same $65050$ digits of the largest known prime? ...

Answer (score 2):

Take your prime $a$ with $65050$ digits and $b = 10^{65051}$. Then according Direchlet theorem this progression $a + bn$ has infinitely many prime numbers, because they ($a$ and $b$) are coprime.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many such primes (the largest known prime technically being the first) according to [Dirchlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

*Remark:* This is only correct because the largest known prime is neither $2$ nor $5$.

Comment: Can this question be done without using Dirichlet's theorem and by simple pre-calculus?